# search in windows 7 does not show where it is looking

Tags: windows-7, search

When I search for something in windows 7, it does not show me where it is looking. In windows XP, the search facility used to tell me where it was looking as it searched.

Is there any way to get windows 7 to do the same thing?

Comment: Do you mean the specific location it is looking, or just where the results are found?

Comment: @JoshuaNurczyk I mean the specific location that it is looking.

Comment: Can I ask, what is, or is there a specific reason you want to see this? Just for a bit of context on the problem @starbeamrainbowlabs

Comment: @MalwareManiac When I run searches with windows 7, it quite often goes for a while without finding anything. I just want something that gives we an indicator of how fast it is searching. Knowing where it is searching is also a nice-to-have feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, the level of available detail and options for file searching regressed significantly between windows XP and Vista/7. Most likely, current location is not shown for searches because by default Windows 7 is not performing a "real" search of the filesystem, but rather searching the Search Index. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) describes the process in more detail. Unfortunately, even if the Windows Search service is disabled, these details remain obscured.

If you are looking for a more XP-like search, My favorite alternative is [Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home), which exposes many more options and *does* indicate where it is currently searching.  It can also be made to replace the standard Windows Search function when ctrl+F is pressed.

Comment: Thanks! I have search indexing disabled as most often I want to search those places that are not included in the index.